# Restoring MS SQL TDE database question

Tags: sql-server, transparent-data-encryption

I'm new to SQL Server TDE and have a question.

I have two VM's (VM1 = Source and VM2 = Target).  On the source machine, I executed all the required steps to enable my Test database as well as backing up the certificate and private key.  No issues here.

On the target machine, i executed the following t-sql commands

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION

CREATE CERTIFICATE
FROM FILE
WITH PRIVATE KEY(
FILE
DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD
);
```

without any issue and successfully restored my Test TDE database.

On the source machine, I had to run this command

```
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
```

but I didn't have to when I did the restore on the target machine.  Here's my question:  Is my Test database on the target machine TDE enabled?

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

> On the source machine, I executed all the required steps to enable my
>   Test database as well as backing up the certificate and private key.
>   No issues here.

We don't really know the steps you took.

Here is a query you can run to see if the database is encrypted on the target server.  Look at the EncryptionState column.

```
SELECT 
    db_name(database_id) as DatabaseName, 
    Case 
        when encryption_state=0 then 'No Database Encryption'
        when encryption_state=1 then 'Unencrypted'
        when encryption_state=2 then 'Encryption In Progress'
        when encryption_state=3 then 'Encrypted'
        when encryption_state=4 then 'Key Change In Progress'
        when encryption_state=5 then 'Decryption In Progress'
        when encryption_state=6 then 'Protection Changes In Progress'
    end as EncryptionState,
    percent_complete
FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys
```

Comment: 3. Created a "Test" database
4. Ran CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION
5. Ran CREATE CERTIFICATE
6. Ran CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
7. Ran ALTER DATABASE Test SET ENCRYPTION ON
8. Ran BACKUP CERTIFICATE TO FILE WITH PRIVATE KEY 
9. BACKUP DATABASE Test

Comment: After that, I took the backup db and copied the certificate and private key to the target
machine to perform the restore.

I ran your sample statement, "tempdb" was the only one that came back.  I had already checked this
before posting.  Here's my confusion.  When I right click on my Test db -> Properties -> Options ->
scroll down and I saw this

Encryption Enabled = True

So I am conflicted results.

Is my restored Test TDE db on the target still TDE enabled??

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to format nicely on my replies.  But that what I did on the source machine in my replies above.

Comment: @sydney - can you update your question and include the backup command you ran on the source server?  I'm wondering if your restore actually restored the encrypted database from the source.

Comment: @sydney - when you right-clicked on your test db and looked at properties, did you do that on the source or target server?

Comment: Scott, the backup test db is/was encrypted.  When I first tried to restore it without restoring the certificate, it told me I needed the certificate on the target machine.  I looked at the Test db properties on the target machine.

Comment: Scott, you can also see my Step 7 that I ran on the source to enable TDE.

Comment: @sydney - I'm out of ideas.  I don't know why your target database would not show up as encrypted given the information you've provided.  What happens if you try to `SET ENCRYPTION ON` on the target database?

Comment: When I run SET ENCRYPTION ON, I get this error:

Msg 33107, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Cannot enable database encryption because it is already enabled.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

Comment: When I run this tsql, I only see "tempdb"

select 
d.name,
dek.*
from sys.databases d
join sys.dm_database_encryption_keys dek
on d.database_id = dek.database_id

Comment: So I'm not sure what's going on.  A true test would be to run a BACKUP on the target machine and try to restore it onto a 3rd machine.

Comment: I figured it out.  I need to be in my "Test" database when I run sys.dm_database_encryption_keys.  I probably was in "master" and that's why I didn't see it yesterday.